# Building ParaView-Superbuild in MacOS

Tags: paraview

I'm trying to build ParaView in MacOS. I went to the repository `https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/tree/master` which lead me to build paraview-superbuild
`https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview-superbuild/tree/v5.7.0``

Following instructions I executed

```
$ cd paraview-superbuild
$ git fetch origin # ensure you have the latest state from the main repo
$ git checkout v5.7.0 # replace `v5.7.0` with tag name of your choice
$ git submodule update
```

Then

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

And I'm getting the error

```
-- Found Git: /usr/local/bin/git (found version "2.21.0")
-- Determined source version for paraview: 5.7.0
CMake Error at superbuild/cmake/SuperbuildMacros.cmake:481 (message):
  The build tree appears to be inside of the git repository located at
  /Users/username/Desktop/dev/paraview/paraview-superbuild.  This interferes
  with the way the superbuild applies patches to projects and is not
  supported.  Please relocate the build tree to a directory which is not
  under a git repository.
```

What is happening here? Was cmake execute in the right folder? because there are more CMakeList.txt inside paraview-superbuild.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you script, it looks like you created a `build` directory as a subdirectory of the `paraview-superbuild` directory. The error message is telling you that that location for the build directory is not supported.

Instead, you could create the `build` directory as a sibling of `paraview-superbuild` or anywhere else on your file system not inside the `paraview-superbuild` directory.